# Maximal (or prime) theories and their sets

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, modal-logic, intuitionistic-logic

Probably it is very simple lemma but I cannot see it. Suppose that we have intuitionistic propositional logic (in fact, it can be classical) and $W$ is the set of all prime (or maximal - in classical setting) theories. Let $|\varphi|$ be the proof set (or the so-called prime set) of formula $\varphi$, defined as such: $|\varphi| = \{z \in W; \varphi \in z\}$. Now the lemma is: if $|\varphi| = |\psi|$ then $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$. I understand that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent on the ground of prime theories from $|\varphi|$ and $|\psi|$ but why $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ must be theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Any filter (consistent theory) in distributive lattice is the intersection of the prime filters (prime theories) containing it, by Zorn's lemma. So in your situation, the filter generated by $\phi$ must be the same as the filter generated by $\psi$, because they are intersections of the same thing. (I allow theories generated by statements that are not sentences, but I imagine the argument is very analogous howsoever you define theories.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I have certain "feeling" but... What's the relation between filters and theorems?

Comment: If you introduce a preorder on formulas by $\vdash$, then consistent theories (or theorem sets of consistent theories) correspond to the filters on the preordered set (of formulas). Unless you demand that theories be generated by sentences (formulas with no free variables), in which case consistent theories correspond to filters generated by sentences.